# Are LUIS model features lost in Dispatch model created with botframework cli tool?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

In the last days I spent few time in fine tuning a LUIS model of a Botframework Skill. I found really useful to use "Phrase list" feature to define synonyms and obtain a better behavior from the skill bot.

Unfortunately when I connect the Skill to the Bot, I notice that the "Phrase list" features are no more present in the dispatch model created by the cli tools.

Is this a known behavior/limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch CLI combined phraselists into new ones to make sure the new Dispatch phrase lists are under the quota.  Could you check if specific words you are looking for are under the phraselists created by Dispatch?

Comment: Hi @Tien,
there is not phraselist at all inside the Features section of the Dispatch model page on LUIS portal.